# A file based database for php with pdo

Tags: php, database, sqlite, pdo

what kind of file type database engine can you suggest for using with php and pdo? I want to avoid user restrictions on the mysql package the service provider gives me; What can php database drivers do for me for creating a database for me without configuring the php.ini because I have no access to it either; I heard about sqlite, can sqlite solve my problem?

my limitations are number of databases, creating database users, jobs, etc.
so I can use the providers mysql server for creating tables and inserting, deleting or manipulating records. I want to play with stored procedures, scheduled jobs or db users if I can.

Comment: Sqlite sounds like a good bet, take a look at its manual to find out whether it will work for you. What kind of provider restrictions are you talking about though? Limits in data? Maximum number of tables? Databases?

Comment: @Pekka I added a second paragraph to the question.

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan: SQLite doesn't really provide any of that, and I'm pretty sure there isn't any other that will give you what you're after, but if you just want to play around, why not try installing LAMP, MAMP or WAMP -- depending on preferred OS -- on your own computer?

Comment: If the hosting provider doesn't have sqlite installed you'll be SOL there as well.  At the end of the day most services in a shared environment are restricted.  If the MySQL setup is limiting for your needs, it will probly be a matter of time until another restriction hampers you.  sqlite doesn't even have a concept of users btw, it's rather minimal.

Answer (score 0):

look at sqlite, it will be good for some of the things you want.  Otherwise install mysql on your own machine and play around with it as much as you want.  The community version is free and available on Windows, Mac and Linux.

- [MySql Download Page](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/)
- [PHP Doc Pages for SQLITE](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php)
- [SQLITE home page](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to play with stored procedures, scheduled jobs or db users if I can.

Stored procedures and scheduled jobs [are *way* beyond SQLite's abilities](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) - as they are beyond anything else file-based that you can install on a shared hosting package without root privileges.

Maybe you need a small virtual server instead? One where you can install whatever you like. Depending on what your situation and location is, there might be affordable Linux-based packages out there.

Comment: You're absolutely right, to quote SQLite's homepage: *In order to achieve simplicity, SQLite has had to sacrifice other characteristics that some people find useful, such as high concurrency, fine-grained access control, a rich set of built-in functions, stored procedures, esoteric SQL language features, XML and/or Java extensions, tera- or peta-byte scalability, and so forth.* http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html